# Express use router with a slug in path

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have build a `categoryRouter` that has several routes. I want to use that router in another router but also specify a slug, like this:
`parentRouter.use('/:slug/categories', categoryRouter)`

It seems that the `req.params` object is empty inside `categoryRouter` routes.

Example code:

**`In "index.js" file:`**

```
const express = require('express');
const productsRouter = require('./products-router');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const apiRouter = express.Router();
apiRouter.use('/products', productsRouter);

app.use('/api', apiRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

**`In "products-router.js" file:`**

```
const express = require('express');
const categoryRouter = require('./category-router');

const productsRouter = express.Router();
productsRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('[GET] - Products root!');
});

productsRouter.use('/:productId/category', categoryRouter);

module.exports = productsRouter;
```

**`In "category-router.js" file:`**

```
const express = require('express');

const categoryRouter = express.Router();
categoryRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.params); // outputs {}

    res.send('[GET] - categoryRouter root!');
});

categoryRouter.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params); // outputs {}

    res.send('[POST] - categoryRouter root!');
});

module.exports = categoryRouter;
```

When i specified the whole path inside `categoryRouter` routes like this:

```
categoryRouter.get('`/:productId/category`', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.params);
    res.send('[GET] - categoryRouter root!');
});
```

And also change the path inside `productsRouter`:

`productsRouter.use('/', categoryRouter);`

Does anyone know how can i make this work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: How can there be anything in the params if the path is `/`?

Comment: @Konrad I was expecting that it would work considering this line `productsRouter.use('/:productId/category', categoryRouter);`. There is a slug/param in that path. But i also understand that it makes sense not to work. What i cannot figure out is what is the best approach to make this work

Answer (score 0):

Declare the product and category routes separately:

```
const express = require('express');

const productsRouter = express.Router();

productsRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('[GET] - Products root!');
});

productsRouter
    .route('/:productId/category')
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.send('[GET] - categoryRouter root!');
    })
    .post((req, res) => {
        res.send('[POST] - categoryRouter root!');
    });

module.exports = productsRouter;
```

And use them with:

```
const express = require('express');
const productsRouter = require('./products-router');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use('/api/products', productsRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Hmm, is this the only way? Isn't there a workaround to keep the architecture as it is? Then in my use case it is suitable to put the routes directly inside `productsRouter`, i was looking for a clearer and nicer approach to do it.

Comment: @Cache You can use a single route file if you need. Check edited answer.